# ownership of file is changing automatically

Tags: linux, file-permissions, rpm

How can I prevent changing the ownership of a file?
I have a file with permission as follows:

```
-rw-r-----. 1 netcool ncoadmin 1689 May  8 14:54 NCI_Constellation.proj
```

As part of RPM package installation, I am running a script which is supposed to write data into NCI_Constellation.proj file. Whereas the permission of the file is getting changed as follows during package installation and the writing to the file is not happening.

```
-rw-r-----. 1 root root 1689 May  8 14:54 NCI_Constellation.proj
```

Is there a way to not change the ownership of NCI_Constellation.proj file and keep it as it is as follows so that I will be able to write data to the file?

```
-rw-r-----. 1 netcool ncoadmin 1689 May  8 14:54 NCI_Constellation.proj
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The question is: what package does that file belong to and with what permissions?

```
rpm -qf /path/to/NCI_Constellation.proj
```

will give you the package owning this file (let's say `NCI.rpm`). Then

```
rpm -qlv NCI.rpm | grep NCI_Constellation.proj
```

will give you the owners and rights of this file as packaged by `NCI.rpm`. If you are the one packaging NCI.rpm; you should put something like this in your `%files` section:

```
%files
%attr(640,netcool,ncoadmin) /path/to/NCI_Constellation.proj
```

By the way make sure that you really can write to the file with those permissions; test that first... Who is running the script to change this file? As which user? then run it yourself manually as that user to make sure these file permissions will suffice.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Chris Maes, I tried your suggestion but it didn't work for me. I tried to set the suid and sgid as well. But that also didn't work :-(

Comment: "that didn't work" is rather vague. You need to dig in more. Who is setting the file permissions? What file permissions are the files installed with? Is someone really changing the permissions or are they just installed correctly by your rpm? What if you change permissions to 777 (for testing),...

Answer (score 1):

you have two options in my opinion,

first : set netcool to root group by doing this:
`$ sudo usermod -a -G root netcool`
with this command you user is able to change and modify the file even after the permissions changed.

second : set netcool user a second root user by changing `/etc/passwd` file.
for this open the file with every file-editor you want then change UID and GID to 0. after doing this if you run `$ grep netcool /etc/passwd` you should see :
`netcool:x:0:0: {the rest may change for anybody}`.

Answer (score 0):

We can prevent the changing of group of file by using setgid bit on directory. So if you add user netcool to ncoadmin and give write permission to ncoadmin then you can edit the file. Here is how you can set the SetGid bit on directory.

`chmod g+s your_directory_containing_file(NCI_Constellation.proj)`

**Bit more about the setgid on directory:**

setgid can be used on directories to make sure that all files inside the directory are owned
by the group owner of the directory. The setgid bit is displayed at the same location as the x
permission for group owner. The setgid bit is represented by an s (meaning x is also there)
or a S (when there is no x for the group owner). As this example shows, even though root
does not belong to the group proj55, the files created by root in /project55 will belong to
proj55 since the setgid is set.

```
root@RHELv4u4:~# groupadd proj55
root@RHELv4u4:~# chown root:proj55 /project55/
root@RHELv4u4:~# chmod 2775 /project55/
root@RHELv4u4:~# touch /project55/fromroot.txt
root@RHELv4u4:~# ls -ld /project55/
drwxrwsr-x 2 root proj55 4096 Feb 7 17:45 /project55/
root@RHELv4u4:~# ls -l /project55/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root proj55 0 Feb 7 17:45 fromroot.txt
```